# how to output the result?

Tags: php

```
Array
(
[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 9
        [vid] => 3
        [name] => Domestic 
        [description] => Domestic 
        [weight] => 0
    )

[12] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 12
        [vid] => 3
        [name] => Economic 
        [description] => Economic 
        [weight] => 1
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 11
        [vid] => 3
        [name] => International
        [description] => 
        [weight] => 2
    )


 )
```

supposed the print_r($child) result is the above, how i want to echo  all the tid and the name, how should i do?

```
foreach($child as $arr){
 foreach($arr as $key=>$vaule)
{
...
```

i don't know how to loop out them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should print the data out for you.

```
foreach($child as $arr)
{

   echo 'Tid: ' . $arr->tid . ' and Name: ' . $arr->name . "\n";
}
```

You may wish to add the appropriate HTML tags to format it.

Comment: it output nothing. GDD answer is ok

Comment: Oops - did not notice that the elements are objects. Corrected it.

Comment: you can try this one : $arr['tid']

Comment: @syed.ahmed - The items are `stdClass Object` - I made the mistake first of assuming that it was an array also.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($child as $arr)
{
   echo "output: ".$arr->tid." ".$arr->name;
}
```

Comment: Even if your solution might be good, adding a little comment on how it works won't harm and will allow the OP understand better your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert object to array with this `php` function

```
<?PHP

function object2array($data)
{
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$key] = object2array($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $data;
}

?>
```

After using this function you can use this code.

```
foreach($child as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
        if($key == "tid" || $key == "name")
        {
            // Here some code
        }
    }
}
```